# sql statement insert into with select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with columns:

```
StudentID
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

...and I have three queries, each one will come with the studentID and a value(1 to 3) fields

What I would like to do is to update this table, with parallel values, if a student exists then update the corresponding column if not, create a new row.

I'm working with SQL Server 2005

Comment: Is this homework? Ideally you would use the merge syntax, but that wasn't available until SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like you just said it:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE StudentID = @StudentID)
BEGIN
--update
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--insert
END
```